# Make ltablex inline rather than centered across textwidth

Tags: tables, longtable, page-breaking, tabularx, ltablex

I'm using `ltablex` to make a long `tablularx` environment. I notice that it seems to centre the table across the page rather than putting it inline like `tabularx` does. This causes problems for me because I want the table as part of an `enumerate` list.

How can I make the table return to being set inline?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,ltablex}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Some text.

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
      \toprule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

### Output

Page 1:

[image: ltablex page 1]

Page 2:

[image: ltablex page 2]

### Output without `ltablex` for comparison

This was created just with `\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}`. Notice that the table lines up with the text in the enumerate environment:

[image: tabularx page 1]

Comment: longtable are necessarily full width, to allow page breaking but you can set `\LTleft` to `\leftmargin` to get the same indent as the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,ltablex}
\keepXColumns
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Some text.
    {
    \setlength\LTleft\fill
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
      \toprule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \midrule
      a & b \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    }
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]